# Django - 500 Internal Server Error в ajax post request

Tags: html, jquery, python, ajax, django

Всем доброго времени суток

При каждом post запросе у меня вылезает ошибка в консоли браузера: `jquery.js:4 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/send/ 500 (Internal Server Error)`. Происходит она в библотеке jQuery в методе send.

Код:

csrf.js:

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

sendMsg.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#message-form').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var message = $('#message').val();
        document.getElementById('message').value = "";
        if (message !== '') {
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/send/',
                dataType: 'text',
                data: { msg: message },
                success: function () {
                    alert("Message sent!");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error occured!");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

html форма:

```
<form class="chat-form" name="message-form" id="message-form" action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <textarea title="message" form="message-form" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Type a message..."></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" name="send">
 </form>
```

views.py:

```
class MessageManager(APIView):
    @csrf_protect
    def post(self, request):
        msg = request.POST.get('msg', None)
        if msg != '':
            time = str(datetime.time.isoformat)
            author = request.user.username
            new_message = Message.objects.create(msg=msg, time=time, author=author)
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(new_message), content_type="application/json")
        return HttpResponse(status=400)
```

url:

```
url(r'^send/$', views.MessageManager.as_view())
```

Где может быть ошибка ?

Comment: Включайте `DEBUG = True`, читайте что сервер отвечает

Comment: Что в логах сервера?

Comment: Очевидно ошибка в json.dumps , которая умеет общаться с list, но не с queryset.